# How do I use an command line "flag" variable in SSH command?

Tags: bash, ssh

I have an SSH command that is able to use variables defined in the script.

Example:

```
b="03-18-2022"
```

I'm able to pass this in to my ssh call and use it.

However I want to be able to define `$b` when I run the script: `bash file.sh -b 03-18-2022`

.. When I try doing this the SSH command cannot recognize the variable

CODE:

Getting the variable from the input:

```
while getopts ":b:" arg; do
  case "${arg}" in
    b) b="$OPTARG";;
  esac
done

echo "Locally using begin: $b 
printf -v b_str %q "$b"
ssh myserver "bash -s $b_str"  << 'EOF'
b=$1
echo "remotely using $b"
```

The last echo works when the variable is defined in the script but not when it is passed in from the command line

Comment: Your code has some serious issues. Use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net).

Comment: setting aside the syntax issues ... a) before the `ssh` call add `typeset -p b b_str` (when you run the script this will display the contents of these 2x variables - do they contain what you expect them to contain?) and b) before the last `echo` you have `b=$1` which is going to overwrite whatever was in `b` (what's the purpose of `b=$1` in this scenario?)

Comment: @markp-fuso  I was trying to parse the string to allow it to work in the SSH... then set b=$1.. it echos the correct parameter in ssh, without it it sets the variable b is empty